# Let G be a finite group and let H and K be a subgroup of G so that [G:K] and |H| are relatively prime. Prove that [G:K]|H| divides |G|

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

So this is the proof:

By Lagrange's Theorem we know

$|G|=[G:K]|K|$

$|G|=[G:H]|H|$

Than we know that $|H|$ divides $|G|=[G:K]|K|$

Since $[G:K]$ and $|H|$ are relatively prime, than $|H|$ must divide $|K|$

So let $n$ be any natural number so the $|K|=|H|n$

Than $|G|=[G:K]|K|=[G:K]|H|n$

Which implies that $[G:K]|H|$ divides $|G|$

I have a couple of questions:

1.Why does knowing that

$|G|=[G:K]|K|$

$|G|=[G:H]|H|$

imply that $|H|$ divides $|G|=[G:K]|K|$ ?

1. Why $[G:K]$ and $|H|$ being relatively prime imply that $|H|$ divides $|K|$?

Answer (score 3):

$\rm\: |H|\:[G:H] = |G|\:\Rightarrow\: |H|\:$ divides $\rm\,|G|,\:$ by definition. The second inference in question follows by Euclid's Lemma $\rm\ gcd(a,b)=1,\ a\mid bc\:\Rightarrow\: a\mid c.\:$

Comment: So since |H| divides |G| and |G|=[G:K]|K| than |H| divides |G|=[G:K]|K|?

Comment: Yes, if $\rm\,\ a\mid d\ $ and $\rm\ d = bc\ $ then $\rm a\mid bc\ \ $ by basic equational logic (replacement of equal values).

Comment: That makes complete sense, thanks!